# Laravel laravel cross database relationships wherehas goes wrong

Tags: laravel

I have configured two database connections:

```
        'sqlsrv' => [
            'driver' => 'sqlsrv',
            'host' => env('DB_HOST', '####'),
            'port' => env('DB_PORT', '####'),
            'database' => env('DB_DATABASE', '####'),
            'username' => env('DB_USERNAME', '####'),
            'password' => env('DB_PASSWORD', '####'),
            'charset' => 'utf8',
            'prefix' => 'pref1_',
            'prefix_indexes' => true,
        ],

        'sqlsrv1' => [
            'driver' => 'sqlsrv',
            'host' => env('DB_HOST1', '####'),
            'port' => env('DB_PORT1', '####'),
            'database' => env('DB_DATABASE1', '####'),
            'username' => env('DB_USERNAME1', '####'),
            'password' => env('DB_PASSWORD1', '####'),
            'charset' => 'utf8',
            'prefix' => '',
        ],
```

With the normal user model and 2 custom models:

**Synergy:**

```
    class Synergy extends Model
    {
        protected $connection = 'sqlsrv1';
        protected $table = 'humres';
        protected $primaryKey = 'res_id';
        public $timestamps = false;

    public function user(){
        return $this->belongsTo('App\User', 'employee_id', 'res_id');
    }
```

**PushNotification:**

```
    class PushNotification extends Model
    {

    public function user(){
        return $this->belongsTo('App\User');
    }
```

I want to check if the user has a permission for push notification and if another column is set on true. 
I try it with this query:

```
       $users = User::with('PushNotification')->with('Synergy')
            ->whereHas('PushNotification', function($q){
                $q->where('type', 'news')->where('active', 1);
            })
            ->whereHas('Synergy', function($q1){
                $q1->where('freefield20', 1);
            })
            ->get();
        return $users;
```

It throws the following error:

```
SQLSTATE[42S02]: [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server][SQL Server]Invalid object name 'pref1_humres'. (SQL: select * from [pref1_users] where exists (select * from [pref1_push_notifications] where [pref1_users].[id] = [pref1_push_notifications].[user_id] and [type] = news and [active] = 1) and (exists (select * from [pref1_humres] where [pref1_users].[employee_id] = [pref1_humres].[res_id] and [freefield20] = 1)))
```

Why does it use the prefix of **sqlsrv** while with **sqlsrv1** no prefix is entered?

Any ideas how to build this query correctly?

Comment: You are using `whereHas` on model User. plz post the Synergy relationship in User model.

Comment: This is de Synergy relationship in the User model:
`public function Synergy(){
        return $this->hasOne('App\Synergy', 'res_id', 'employee_id');
    }`